# Is there a passive component able to stabilize current (as zeners can do with voltage)?

Tags: zener, passive-components

So I need a component which will have a flat сurrent–voltage characteristic (constant current in a wide voltage range).

Initially I was intended to ask a general question: **what kind of the device can do this function**. However some of commentators wished more details so I'm putting them into the question:

*For the moment I need that the device can be supplied with voltage as low as 1V (I wish it could be even lower) and drive current in scale of tens of microAmsp. The precision of the current should be something within 10% in range of voltage between 1 and 10V and in typical industrial temperature range.*

Comment: Saturated transistor?

Comment: @ScottSeidman, it will have so big dependence on a temperature, on a manufacturing circumstances and finally I will need an additional current source to the base. I need something precise as zener can do with a voltage.

Comment: A constant current diode (or current limit diode). See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-current_diode)

Comment: @SteveG, so literally it's a combination of depletion mode FET with a resistor? Actually I implemented this schematic for current limiting purposes (basing on BSS126) but the current is widely depend on a Vgs voltage which depends on temperature and other circumstances. So I thought that it is not any precise solution. Is it?

Comment: What current through the device? Supply voltage? Max and min voltage across the current source?

Comment: @Transistor, actually my requirements are pretty hard: Supply voltage can be as low as 1V (I'd wish even lower), current should be pretty small: something like tens of microAmps.

Comment: Why did you ask a question, only to clarify your requirements in comments?  Can you edit your question to include all the specs you're interested in meeting?  It might help in generating a meaningful answer.

Comment: @RomanMatveev: Your comments only make the question worse. Please give a full user requirements **in the question** including details requested in my previous comment. You probably also need to state whether the load is ground references, supply referenced or floating.

Comment: @Transistor, please check my edit. Do you think that the question is better now?

Comment: "_I need that the device can be supplied with voltage as low as 1V ..._" It's not clear what the "device" is. Is it the whole circuit or a device under test? Why don't you explain what the real problem you are trying to solve is? Again, you probably also need to state whether the load is ground references, supply referenced or floating as this will affect the circuit. Add a schematic of what your setup will be.

Comment: @Transistor, I have a bad experience with putting "extra" details into the question as some contributors answered not the question I asked. It was a nightmare :((( Probably it is due to my poor English... Now I'd like to have an answer on the question I stated (and I actually have a good answer by IGBC). I really don't understand why I CAN'T ask a question in general?!

Comment: (1) Because the solution will depend on the power level and voltage involved. In your case an opamp might suffice but there's no clue in the original question about whether it's microamps or hundreds of amps, millivolts or kV (wide voltage range). (2) The circuit may be quite simple if the load is a resistor connected to ground. It may be more complex otherwise. I've had the opposite problem to you - I've spent a lot of time answering questions only to find that the OP had left out crucial information that meant my time was wasted. ;^)

Comment: Roman, I think it would help if we know WHY you were trying to do this.  It seems like it might be an overly complicated approach to some problem, and maybe there's a more straightforward way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ScottSeidman In this case I'd better create a separate question.

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is called a "constant current source". Unfortunately these are not passive components, however luckily they are available in 3 pin IC form that are very easy to implement into your circuit.

Here is an example product: http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/constant-current-diodes/5359098/

Datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm134.pdf

From the data sheet implement it like this:

[image: Constant current source application note.]

- Connect the V+ pin to your supply voltage (it should be quite stable)
- Connect the R pin to a resistor to V-, the current through the resistor proportionally controls the current out from the output.
- The output current is provided by V- and the current through the set resistor.

These parts are also available with fixed output currents hardwired into them. They can be slightly cheaper.

Comment: This solution is big and expensive in my case, but it is much better than I had before! Thank you for the idea!

Comment: there are very small surface mount versions available, and non programmable versions that are cheaper. have a search around your favourate supplier for whats available.